# Problemas con Selenium + Python (Mi escript detectado como malware en Chrome y selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'FireFox)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy probando Selenium por primera vez. Solo he escrito cuatro lineas de código y ya tengo problemas:

Primero intenté trabajar con Chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

_chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
_chrome_options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=_chrome_options)

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.close()
```

Se ejecuta bien, pero al abrirse el navegador me sale un mensaje del programa antimalware de Microsoft y la página se cierra automaticamente tan rapido que no me da tempo ni a leerla.

```
"""
Herramienta de eliminación de software malintenc. de Microsoft quiere restablecer la configuración predeterminada original de Chrome. 

Se restablecerá la página principal, la página Nueva pestaña y el motor de búsqueda. Asimismo, se inhabilitarán las extensiones y no se fijará ninguna pestaña. 

También se borrarán los datos temporales y los almacenados en la memoria caché, como las cookies, el contenido y los datos de sitios. Más información
"""
```

He intentado desinstalar esta herramienta de Microsoft por dos motivos, primero porque no hace bien su trabajo y segundo porque no me deja programar... pero no está en la lista de programas instalados y no le encuentro por ningun lado. ¿Alguien sabe como eliminar esta molesta herramienta o por lo menos deshabilitarla o hacer una excepción para que deje ejecutar mi escript? El script lo queiro para ejecutarlo en mi máqina así que no me importa si no funciona en otras.

También intenté hacerlo con FireFox a ver si así tenia mas suerte

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.FireFox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.close()
```

Pero me sale este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.FireFox()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'FireFox'
```

Probablemente esa forma de hacerlo ha quedado deprecada...  Así que no he podido hacer absolutamente nada con Selenium. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Hola Iván, no te puedo ayudar mucho con el tema de Windows, no suelo trabajar mucho con él, en cuanto al problema de Firefox, el error es solo tipográfico, es `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`, la segunda `f` es en minúscula. no lo había probado desde antes de la salida de Quantum, lo acabo de hacer con Python 3.6 junto  Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 sin problemas aparentes.

Comment: En cuanto al primer problema, mira a ver si esta pregunta de SO te es de ayuda: [Window defender wants to reset your setting" -ChromeDriver 2.29 issue:ChromeBrowser opening with a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961793/window-defender-wants-to-reset-your-setting-chromedriver-2-29-issuechromebrow)

Comment: Hola!! Ok, así si funciona!! y lo mejor es que no me salta el antimalware...  perfecto, ya puedo empezar a trabajar!! :-) Muchas gracias @FJSevilla

Comment: Ley doy un vistazo a ese link!! Muchas gracias!!